# Using functional form when list item is dependent on earlier items

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have list of tuples which each tuple has length of element. I use following code to calculate offset of element depending on lengths of earlier elements.

```
import pprint
recordInfo = [(3,), (4,), (1,), (2,)]  # List of lengths
# Calculate and add offsets
recordSize = 0
for index, info in enumerate(recordInfo):
    recordInfo[index] = info + ( recordSize, )  # Replace with new tuple with offset
    recordSize += info[0]  # Calculate next offset
pprint.pprint(recordInfo)
```

Output is

```
[(3, 0), (4, 3), (1, 7), (2, 8)]
```

Is there a way to do the loop in functional form, like list comprehension? I cannot figure out how to avoid temporary variable `recordSize`, which makes it impossible?

Comment: Are you on Python 2 or 3? Python 3 has [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), which perfectly solves your problem.

Comment: @user2357112 Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, and it's not efficient, but here is a list comprehension that does what you requested:

```
>>> recordInfo = [(3,), (4,), (1,), (2,)]
>>> [info + (sum(_info[0] for _info in recordInfo[:i]),)
         for i,info in enumerate(recordInfo)]
[(3, 0), (4, 3), (1, 7), (2, 8)]
```

It works by recalculating the offset up to the current item at each iteration, hence it's inefficient.

It works on both Python 2 & 3.

Comment: That is pretty nice actually. I hadn't thought of using `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> recordInfo = [3, 4, 1, 2]

>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + [(y, sum(x[-1]))], recordInfo, [(0, 0)])[1:]
[(3, 0), (4, 3), (1, 7), (2, 8)]

>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> list(zip(recordInfo, [0] + list(accumulate(recordInfo))))
[(3, 0), (4, 3), (1, 7), (2, 8)]
```

If you have tuples:

```
>>> recordInfo = [(3, 'a'), (4, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'd')]

>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + [y + (x[-1][0] + x[-1][-1], )], recordInfo, [(0, )])[1:]
[(3, 'a', 0), (4, 'b', 3), (1, 'c', 7), (2, 'd', 8)]

>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [x + (c,) for x, c in zip(recordInfo, accumulate(map(itemgetter(0), [(0,)] + recordInfo)))]
[(3, 'a', 0), (4, 'b', 3), (1, 'c', 7), (2, 'd', 8)]
```

Comment: Does these work with tuples? In my real code tuples in `recordInfo` actually have more data before operation.

Comment: Do you want to keep the original data and just append the accumulated value then?

Comment: Kind of, yes. In original data each tuple has 3 fields, and after operation there is 4 fields in each tuple. I just removed 2 unrelated fields to keep my question simple.

Comment: Edited my answer; but it’s getting quite messy now… :/

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you meant by functional but hey, always fun.

```
def increment_record(records, size=0):
     if not records:
         return []
     return [(records[0], size)] + increment_record(records[1:], size=size+records[0])
```

But yeah, I don't think this is really a pattern python allows a person to address in a manner without local state (unless of course you use a high level function like the aforementioned itertools.aggregate that just conceals the state). Of course, if you really needed to you could just define some sort of counting object (or use a closure).

```
class Tallier(object):
     def __init__(self, val):
          self._val = val

     def tally(self, new_val):
          old_val = self._val
          self._val += new_val
          return old_val

[(val, tallier.tally(val)) for val in values]
```

Comment: Yes, not really what I meant. I want to avoid recursion.